# Make one div containing a table into two divs containing tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that gets raw HTML to output to a table, but I want to take out the first three columns and put them in another div.

I am considering making a div on the page that is hidden, setting this div's html to the raw HTML I get, and then using the selector syntax to strip it into each table's div.  Is there a way to do this without the intermediate faux-div to hold the raw HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you'd want to do this, rather than arrange your data server-side, but one approach that works is:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('table').click(
            function(){
                $('<table />').appendTo('#newTable').addClass('new');
                $('table').eq(0).find('tr td:first-child').each(
                    function(){
                        $(this).appendTo('.new').wrap('<tr></tr>');
                    });
            });
    });
```

With the (x)html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1:1</td>
        <td>1:2</td>
        <td>1:3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2:1</td>
        <td>2:2</td>
        <td>2:3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3:1</td>
        <td>3:2</td>
        <td>3:3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4:1</td>
        <td>4:2</td>
        <td>4:3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="newTable"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wxdrk/)

The demo uses [jQuery's `click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event, but that's just to show it working interactively; it could certainly be placed straight into the DOM-ready/`$(document).ready(function(){/* ... */});` event.

---

The above code would allow repeated clicks (each time moving the first 'column' into a new table), the edit removes that possibility using [jQuery's `one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), giving the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('table').one('click',
            function(){
                $('<table />').appendTo('#newTable').addClass('new');
                $('table').eq(0).find('tr td:first-child').each(
                    function(){
                        $(this).appendTo('.new').wrap('<tr></tr>');
                    });
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo, featuring `one()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wxdrk/1/).

Comment: Very cool.  I'm trying to set up fixed-columns and want to split up the table into two divs.  My understanding is that appendTo will copy the whole table into the div identified by #newTable, is that correct?

Comment: It splits off, in this case, the first cell of each row, append them to the `.new()` table and wraps each of them in a `tr`. So no, I don't think your assumption is correct, unless I'm misunderstanding. Try one of the JS Fiddle demos, and see if it works for you.

Comment: Ah, an excellent demo!  I think my misunderstanding budded from $('<table/>') and $('table') being different -- the first creates a new <table></table> element which you add to the div, the second one selects all table elements on the page.  Is that right?

Comment: `$('table')` would, by itself, select all tables, however that selection is restricted to only the *first* table by use of the `eq(0)`. You could use `$('table:first')` if you preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends out what the "function that gets raw HTML" does.  Where is it getting the HTML?  If it's in some kind of format other than a rendered node, then you should be able to manipulate it as needed prior to rendering it.  If you've got it in a string format (and the markup is valid) jQuery is really good at turning strings into traversible objects.  For example:

```
var xml = '<div><span>hello</span></div>';
console.log($(xml).find('span'));
```

In FireBug, this displays the span as an object node.

Comment: This is a good point, I'm doing some redundant formatting when I could just do it when I get the html via ajax!  Yes, it's a string with valid markup, but I had no idea you could just traverse them like DOM objects, that is awesome.